# Parsing big XML through digester

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

We are using Digester API from Apache for parsing an xml file. It's working great for small files, but parsing 1.8GB file is really slow. 
XML  structure is really simple. Under profiles tag, it contains list of profile tags.

Its been more than 20 hours, process of creating objects is still on.

Is there a way to improve this ?
Or any specialized library for handling monolithic XML?

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: Do not use Digester for this; use a streaming API such as JAXP or STAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope STAX will helpful for you for large xml file parsing.

http://stax.codehaus.org/Home